# I have installed MySQL for Python . Now I try to connect to the MySQL Community Server on my local machine, using this code:

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.8

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {                                           
            'NAME': "food",
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'groot',
```

This code fails with this error:

...
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "C:\Users\mona\Downloads\food-ordering-system-master\food-ordering-system-master\food-ordering-system\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb_*init*_.py", line 84, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mona\Downloads\food-ordering-system-master\food-ordering-system-master\food-ordering-system\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 179, in **init**
super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")

Comment: Its usually a good idea to start by connecting to your db outside of the django code (such as just in a terminal or shell). You want to verify that mysql is running and that you can actually connect with those settings (user, password, host). As it is, your are just getting the message can't connect - that could be as simple as the service is not running.

Comment: you should follow one of the hundreds of tutorials https://dev.to/sm0ke/how-to-use-mysql-with-django-for-beginners-2ni0 especially the part about migrating

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: have you installed `mysqlclient` ?